# Should I use vegdist or dist for hclust?

Tags: cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering, vegan, hclust, vegdist

I am trying to do a hierarchical cluster analysis with binary data, and for the distance matrix I applied the function `vegdist()` from vegan package:

```
dist.jac <- vegdist(final_df, method="jaccard", binary = TRUE)
```

Next, I used the function hclust but I'm not sure if i should use the dissimilarity matrix produced by `vegdist()`:

```
jac <- hclust(dist.jac, method = "ward.D")
```

or trying something like this (as I've seen):

```
jac <- hclust(dist(dist.jac), method = "ward.D")
```

because the function `hclust()` requires 'a dissimilarity structure as produced by dist'. But on the other hand the vegan package says that "should provide a drop-in replacement for dist and return a distance object of the same type" and "the function is an alternative to dist". It does not make much sense to me apply `dist(dist.jac)` but I've seen doing it so if someone can explain to me which one should I use I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is doing `dist(dist.jac)` they are getting dissimilarities of dissimilarities of data instead of dissimilarities of data. This rarely makes sense.

Like the **vegan** documentation says, `vegdist` is a drop-in replacement of `dist`. It does not matter which one you use. If a dissimilarity is available only in one alternative, use that. If it is available in both, use either. In that case, I would personally prefer `dist` as it does not require calling any contributed packages.